# Responsive pure CSS menu

Tags: html, css

Trying to make a sub-menu appear on hover.

In current state very basic (no styling) just trying to get functionality.

HTML:

```
<nav class="main_nav">
        <ul class="main_nav">
            <li><a class="show_menu" href="#">Menu</a></li>
                <li>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a class="hidden_nav" href="#">Functions</a></li>
                        <li><a class="hidden_nav" href="#">Forms</a></li>
                        <li><a class="hidden_nav" href="#">PHP Info</a></li>
                        <li><a class="hidden_nav" href="#">Encoding</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
        </ul>                   
    </nav>
```

CSS:

```
.hidden_nav {
display: none;
}

.show_menu:hover > .hidden_nav {
display: block;
color: green;
}
```

My problem is with CSS targeting - the above is not the only method I have tried. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `li` elements must be children of `ul`, `ol` or `menu` elements. In your above code, you have a `li` as the child of another `li`. This may be causing some of the issues you're having.

Comment: Yeah I think your'e correct- didn't think of checking my markup too!

Comment: .show_menu:hover > .hidden_nav can't work, as .hidden_nav is not a direct descendant of .show_menu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are some ways you should restructure this. You should set the `ul` of the subnav to be hidden. You can then have the subnav be a sibling or a child (this is a sibling below) and show it when the `.show_menu` parent `li` is hovered:

UPDATE:

HTML

```
<nav class="main_nav">
    <ul class="main_nav">
        <li><a class="show_menu" href="#">Menu</a>
                <ul class="subnav">
                    <li><a class="hidden_nav" href="#">Functions</a></li>
                    <li><a class="hidden_nav" href="#">Forms</a></li>
                    <li><a class="hidden_nav" href="#">PHP Info</a></li>
                    <li><a class="hidden_nav" href="#">Encoding</a></li>
                </ul>
         </li>
    </ul>                   
</nav>
```

CSS

```
.subnav {
  display: none;
 }

.main_nav li:hover ul.subnav {
  display: block;
  color: green;
}
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ddwqbLc5/1/)

Comment: Your markup here is invalid. `ul` elements must not have other `ul` element children. You need to wrap that `ul.subnav` in another `li` element.

Comment: im aware, thanks. Ill rewrite it soon when I have time

Comment: Yes please, wrap your .subnav element into a li, it makes my eyes burn.

Comment: Anyway, I think you gonna have some trouble with this code. When the mouse is outside .show_menu, it will make the .subnav disapear (and unclickable).

Comment: @enguerranws relax, that's a really unnecessary comment

Comment: @user3125923 all fixed

Comment: Just ran into that problem before reading this - thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 0):

This syntax means 'immediate children':

```
.show_menu:hover > .hidden_nav
```

Try this instead:

```
.show_menu:hover .hidden_nav
```

Comment: I thought about this too, but .hidden_nav is not a descendant of .show_menu.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is badly structured for the task you are trying to accomplish. Instead of going into details, I'll show a working - and IMO, stylish - example to help you rapidly.

See it in action: http://jsfiddle.net/xLkntwkt/2/

**HTML**

```
<nav class="main_nav">
    <ul class="main_nav">
        <li>
            <a class="show_menu" href="#">Menu</a>        
            <ul class="hidden_nav">
                <li><a href="#">Functions</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Forms</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">PHP Info</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Encoding</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>

        <li>
            <a class="show_menu" href="#">Menu 2</a>        
            <ul class="hidden_nav">
                <li><a href="#">Functions</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Forms</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">PHP Info</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Encoding</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>

        <li>
            <a class="show_menu" href="#">Menu 3</a>        
            <ul class="hidden_nav">
                <li><a href="#">Functions</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Forms</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">PHP Info</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Encoding</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>                   
</nav>
```

**CSS**

```
ul.main_nav > li {
    background: #333;
    color: #fff !important;
    padding: 10px;
}

ul.main_nav > li a {
    color: inherit;
    text-decoration: none;
}

ul.main_nav > li .hidden_nav {
    max-height: 0px;
    opacity: 0;

    transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;
}

ul.main_nav > li:hover .hidden_nav {
    max-height: 300px;
    opacity: 1;
}
```